# phpPgAdmin does not see databases

Tags: phppgadmin

When I go to databases in phpPgAdmin it says that there are 0 databases. Yet, if I run `SELECT datname FROM pg_database` it displays all databases OK. I would like to be able to 'explore' tables and databases.

Comment: Which account do you use for, respectively, phpPgAdmin and running the `SELECT datname FROM pg_database` query?

Comment: phpPgAdmin probably hides the default databases `template0`, `template1` and `postgres` by default. If there are other DBs, maybe you're connecting to a different DB server from `psql` and phpPgAdmin?

Comment: Milen A. Radev, I use the same account for both running the query and phpPgAdmin. To make matter even more complicated, I run the query from phpPgAdmin which essentialy means that permissions are set correctly.

Comment: Craig Ringer, As per my comment above, I run the query from phpPgAdmin and i displays databases ok.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: omg why is this considered off-topic?
when phppgadmin is configured to see only owned databases, they need to be given to those users, right after creating a new database, not only give privileges, but also ownership: `ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner;`

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the following line of the phpPgAdmin config file (which was duplicate in my config) to

```
$conf['owned_only'] = false;
```